# Sum all the numbers in all the files presents in all subdirectories - complexity?

Tags: java, file, io, directory, time-complexity

Given a root directory, read all the files line by line inside `rootDirectory` or sub directories and sum all the numbers from each file. Each file will have a number in each line. So I just need to read all the files and sum all the numbers and return it. I came up with below code and it does the job (if there is any better or efficient way, let me know)..

I am trying to understand what is the complexity of the below program. If the structure is very deep and we have lot of files in lot of subdirectories then what will be the complexity of the below program. How should we describe the complexity in this case if it is asked in an interview?

```
  private static int count = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sumNumbersInFile("/home/david"));
  }

  private static int sumNumbersInFile(String rootDirectory) {
    if (rootDirectory == null || rootDirectory.isEmpty()) {
      return 0;
    }

    File file = new File(rootDirectory);
    for (File fileEntry : file.listFiles()) {
      if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        count += sumNumbersInFile(fileEntry.getName());
      } else {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileEntry))) {
          String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            count += Integer.parseInt(line);
          }
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

Comment: Let m be the number of files and subdirectories. Let n be the maximum number of lines in the files. Complexity is O(mn)

Comment: Number of Files and number of sub-directories can be different right so do we need to take m for both? Maybe asking very basic question

Comment: m is number of files + + number of subdirectory. Apologies for the ambiguity

Comment: [this might help](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87713/recursion-call-inside-a-for-loop-time)

Comment: @ggbranch it won't be (2^n) because I have recursive function call? I was confuse because of this only.

Comment: Nope. Recursion does not mean 2^n.

Comment: ok.. also complexity will be same in the case where let's say we need to find duplicate files (which has same exact content in it)? It will be O(m) where m is the number of files and subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have `n` files. So, you visit each file once. So that part is `O(n)`. Lets say, `m` is maximum possible number of lines that occurs in that process. You read each line in each file once. So, worst case scenario is that you will read `m` lines in `n` files. So, that makes it `O(n*m)`. You can look at `m` even as average number of lines.

Reason why you need to have both n and m, is because you have two unknown variables, number of files (it doesn't matter if its in one folder on its formatted as one file and one subdirectory in each directory, since you go one by one, you need to visit it all, and you visit it only once each, and number of lines. Each of them can grow independently, so its a function of two unknown. Therefore, its `O(n*m)`.

Even if you put all lines in one file, that would be `O(f(r))`, where `f(r)=g(n*m)`, so it would be still `O(n*m)`, where r is overall number of lines (`r = n * m`). Reason why its different function, but still of same order, its because of factor of traveling trough folders and initiations of file reading, which should be some constant defined before starting of algorithm, which doesn't affect the order of function.

Answer (score 0):

You're still doing only one calculation step per line. The algorithm is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of lines in all files.

Comment: And how about number of files or number of subdirectories? It won't matter here?

Comment: If the number of files or subdirectory exceeds the number of lines (i.e. you have lots of empty files or directories with not file, only further subdirectories), then `n` would become the number of files or directories. But it's still linear complexity.